# Checking of one specific element of one array is in another array?

Tags: mysql, array

Suppose I have two arrays. One looking like `(3, 9, 10, 39)`, and one looking like `(4, 10, 9, 48, 391, 2)`.

How would I (through pure MySQL) check if one of the elements in the first array is inside the other array?

**Edit** By checking, I mean returning true if one item of the first array is occuring in the second array.

Example:

```
SELECT IsElementFromFirstArrayInAnotherArray(array1, array2) AS isInArray
```

Comment: There is no "array" datatype in MySQL. How are the numbers stored in the database? In the same column, one number per row/field? All in the same field, comma-separated?

Comment: array1 is a field with comma-separated values. array2 is a direct array that I parse into the query string with the syntax `(1,2,3,4,2)` etc.